How do I create a const array of pointers to const uint8_t arrays?
I have several const uint8_t arrays of different lengths. I need to create a const array that has a pointer to each (and also preferably a way to automatically calculate the size to another const array).
// uint8_t arrays
const uint8_t SprIdle[] = {
    // bytes of data...
};

const uint8_t SprJump[] = {
    // bytes of data...
};

const uint8_t SprFall[] = {
    // bytes of data...
};

// Pointer arrays
// None of these work
// They all give some variation of:
// a value of type "const uint8_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *const"
const int* SpriteTable[] = {
    SprIdle,
    SprJump,
    SprFall,
};

const int* SpriteTable[] = {
    &SprIdle,
    &SprJump,
    &SprFall,
};

int* const SpriteTable[] = {
    SprIdle,
    SprJump,
    SprFall,
};

int* const SpriteTable[] = {
    &SprIdle,
    &SprJump,
    &SprFall,
};

const int* const SpriteTable[] = {
    SprIdle,
    SprJump,
    SprFall,
};

const int* const SpriteTable[] = {
    &SprIdle,
    &SprJump,
    &SprFall,
};


I have seen some people ask a very similar question with accepted answers, but they don't seem to be working in my case. Most of them should be listed above in the things I've tried.

Why int * when the arrays are arrays of uint8_t elements, which is a very different type? What does the compiler tell you? Doesn't it mention that you have mismatching types?

Are all the uint8_t arrays of the same size?

I'm not entirely certain what your question is asking (the second part mostly), but if you want a resizable array of pointers you can use the std::vector class. Do std::vector<uint8_t *>, then you can use the push back method or the resize method and use the indexing operators to assign new pointers to arrays to that array of pointers.

@Someprogrammerdude But aren't pointers integers?

No they're not. If you dig up your old beginners books or tutorials, they should tell you that arrays decays to pointers to their first element. For example SprIdle will decay to &SprIdle[0]. And since SprIdle is an array of constant uint8_t elements, the type of &SprIdle[0] (and SprIdle) will be const uint8_t *.

And unless you want to modify SpriteTable you should make that constant as well. Like const uint8_t * const SpriteTable[] = { SprIdle , ... };

Choose another language.

Managed to get this to work with the following (including pre-calculating the array sizes):
const uint8_t data0[] = {
    0x00,0x10,0x20
};

const uint8_t data1[] = {
    0xC0,0xE0,0xD0,0xF0
};

const uint8_t *ptrs[] = {
        data0, data1
};

const uint8_t lens[] = {
        sizeof(data0), sizeof(data1)
};

Then I can just read the data with *(ptrs[spriteIndex] + dataOffset).

You probably want const uint8_t* const ptrs[] = {...};.

or best would be const std::span<uint8_t> ptrs[] = {...}; which is basically the same thing, but gives helper methods.

There's a low-level question of "array of structs" vs "struct of arrays" lurking here, too. Depending of access patterns either layout may result in better runtime performance.

Instead of *(ptrs[spriteIndex] + dataOffset) use ptrs[spriteIndex][dataOffset].

Note that lens and ptrs aren't const, they are pointing at const. Const related to a pointer array must be after the *.  const uint8_t * const ptrs[] = 
